# xliff-file vs. database translations

Tags: symfony, translation, xliff

Currently i have not a code-problem, but i dont know which way would be better for me.

For our project, we have two kind of data which would be translatet for the view.

The part, which be coded in the source code like system messages (e.g. You are logged in, log out, etc.)

The second part is the database content like services, there can be added or deleted rows. And not for every entity would be a translation available.

Now i need to know, if i should save and get the translation from a translation table or is it better to transfer (via script) the translation into a services.xliff file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use XLIFF or GetText for the application (source: php, js).
Especially http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSTranslationBundle might be helpful.
The storage mechanism is less important, because of caching. So feel free to use either a DB or files as backend.

User created content is often managed via database. So you might use a common DoctrineExtension, like `translateable`. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html
https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst